# Assigning vs setting params in React Navigation

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

Is it a proper way to change React-Navigation's params' value by assignment:

```
navigation.state.params.number = 123;
```

instead of setting it:

```
navigation.setParams({ number: 123 });
```

I noticed that the first way is synchronous, meaning that I can `console.log(number)` the next line and get the assigned new value, whereas the second way is asynchronous meaning that if I `console.log(number)` on the next line, I will get the old value.

The reason why I need the value to be accessible on the next line is that `state.params` holds the search input in my app and I call action creator to perform a search on the next line, therefore it must be updated before the call.

So, the question, again. Is it a proper way to change the value this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the param value that you assigned on the next line then you can just used the variable that you assigned to param directly rather than reading it from the params.

```
let someValue = 'Foo';

navigation.setParams({ Bar: someValue });
console.log(someValue);
```

`setParams` is used for setting the param for the screen and it updates the `navigationState` with the parameter you set. If you set it directly it will not work as it should be. If you need the parameter you set right after you set it I think you might have a not so ideal logic going on.

Comment: Fair enough. I have been struggling with the issue of what kind of values to keep in state.params for a while since my app's logic requires to maintain the params that are not related to the screens, but to component's communication (when navigating). Thank you for your help!